# error in self-register partner community

Tags: community, controller, error-messages

I set the login of my Partner Community (the image below shows the attributes).
[image]

In my org person account is activated. The profile associated with the partner community user is "partner NXP Pre-Sales". When an external user try to self-register, the system sends my an email with this error:
"There was an error in registering a user for site Demo_NXP_Pre_Sales. You can only register person account portal users as light portal users."
I don't understand how to fix it, can someone help me?
Maybe I have to set up this variable inside the Siteregister Controller

```
private static Id PORTAL_ACCOUNT_ID = '';
```

But i don't understand how.
Thank you fro helping me

Comment: I also tried to create an account an put the id in the SiteRegister controller and put this account in community's login setting. When an external users try to self register , the system sends me the message: "The account associated with this portal has no owner"

Comment: Sounds like a licensing/profile issue, what happens if you setup the registration process to use 'light portal users'?

Comment: How can I do that?